# вынести поиск а результат записать в переменную

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

есть 2 поиска

```
commissionPercent: choices.find((choice) => choice.id === buyer.value)!.commissionPercent,
threadId: choices.find((choice) => choice.id === buyer.value)!.threadId,
```

как вынести поиск а результат поиска записать в переменную что бы потом использовать переменную?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const found = choices.find((choice) => choice.id === buyer.value)
```

и после этого использовать

```
commissionPercent: found.commissionPercent,
threadId: found.threadId,
```